# Is pthread read write lock not working?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I am using pthread read write lock to allow one write thread to a shared memory, and several read thread to read from a shared memory. The memory is a struct that includes a file descriptor (write to and read from disk):

```
typedef struct A{
  ... 
  pthread_rwlock_t rw_lock;  
  b_t* file; 
} A_t;
```

Once in a while, the write thread will read from the file in disk, create a new file, delete the old file, and update `b_t* file` to point to the new file. The read threads will read from the file in disk at any time. To avoid race condition, I use a pthread read write lock on the memory. When  a write thread deletes the file and updates `b_t* file`, it acquires the lock:

```
  pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&A_instance.rw_lock);  

  // destroy next level in disk 
  int r = unlink(filename);

  // rename tmp to be next level file 
  r = rename(tmp_fname, filename);

  pthread_rwlock_unlock(&A_instance.rw_lock);
```

When a read thread do search on the file, it acquires the lock as below:

```
int search(int key){
    int err = pthread_rwlock_rdlock(& A_instance.rw_lock);
    int r = binary_search_in_disk(key);   
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&A_instance.rw_lock);
    return r; 
}
```

Edit: error occurred here:

```
int binary_search_in_disk(key){
  if (!file_exist(filename)){
    return -1;
  }

  FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r”);
  int key;

  num = fscanf(file, "%d%\n", &key);  // error
```

Comment: It's probably some flaw in your code. Usually rwlocks work fine..

Comment: What problems are you having with it exactly?

Comment: You're talking about some field called `file`, but you only manipulate `r`. Are you by any chance assigning it outside of the renamer critical section? Also for the reader - do you have a lock protecting the actual read? the seach result may change *after* leaving the critical section.

Comment: The filename was destroyed when the read thread is searching, which gives a seg fault. It traced back to the binary search. It means that writing is still ongoing when a read thread is attempting to access the file. The critical section is in binary search. I assume by wrapping binary search in the lock, the file reading in the binary search is protected?

Comment: How is `file_exists` implemented?

Comment: int file_exist (char *filename){
  struct stat buffer;   
  return (stat (filename, &buffer) == 0);
}

Comment: Thx all, the issue turned out to be not pthread. Found the issue: `Too many open files`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using shared memory, you presumably have different processes, not just different threads.  As such you need to set the *process-shared* attribute of the rwlock to `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED`.  So the initialization code needs to look like (error checks elided for clarity):

```
    pthread_rwlockattr_t attr;
    pthread_rwlockattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_rwlockattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

    pthread_rwlock_init(&rwlock, &attr);
```

(It feels like there ought to be a more declaritive way of doing this, but I can't see one on the OpenGroup web site).

Comment: Thx Martin! the issue turned out to be not pthread. Found the issue: Too many open files.

Comment: Aaargh!!  I hate that limit.